# About test for diagonalizability. Question about $\operatorname{rank}(T-\lambda I)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> "Let T be a linear operator on an n-dimensional vector space V. Then T is diagonalizaable if and only if:
>
> 1).The characteristic polynomial T splits.
>
> 2). For each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of T, the multiplicity of $\lambda$ equals $n-\operatorname{rank}(T-\lambda I)$

Question: Is $\operatorname{rank}(T-\lambda I)$ the dimension of the eigenspace which makes up the eigenvectors? Why does $n-\operatorname{rank}(T-\lambda I)$ have to equal the multiplicity?

Comment: Use \operatorname{rank}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent $T$ by a matrix $A.$ Then $T- \lambda I$ is represented by $A- \lambda I$. For any $m \times n$ matrix $B$ the dimensiion of the solution space of $B$ is $n-\text {rank} (B)$. So all that the second condition is saying is that the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda$ equals the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace.